# What's the main difference between uWSGI protocol and SCGI?

Tags: webserver, protocols, uwsgi, scgi

I'm currently writing a server that needs to talk to a webserver. I'm not sure what should I use to bridge the gap between my server and the webserver, SCGI or the uWSGI Protocol. At some point I'd swear I read somewhere in the uwsgi [documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Protocol.html) that the uWSGI protocol descends from SCGI but I can't find the line any more.

How do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both serialize a simple list of key-value items. SCGI uses a text format for it while uwsgi (lowercase for the protocol) uses a binary encoding where each string is prefixed with a 16bit size: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Protocol.html

Comment: Why did you not use SCGI?

Comment: I don't understand - parsing uwsgi requires less code or is there something in that half of the code?

Answer (score -1):

Just say one point!

> The uWSGI project aims at developing a full stack for building hosting
>   services.
>
> The uwsgi (lowercase!) protocol is the native protocol used by the
>   uWSGI server.

And answer from [Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/master/FAQ.rst)

> The uwsgi (all lowercase) protocol is derived from SCGI but with
>   binary string length representations and a 4-byte header that includes
>   the size of the var block (16 bit length) and a couple of
>   general-purpose bytes.